# Как загрузить и расшарить файл на Google Drive?

Tags: python, google-drive

Необходимо загрузить файл на google drive, расшарить его и получить общедоступную ссылку.

С загрузкой файла никаких проблем нет, а вот как сделать его общедоступным и получить ссылку нигде информации нет. Кто разбирался с проблемой просьба помочь.

Comment: Можете попробовать сделать это с помощью Google Drive API - https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing?hl=ru

Comment: @Danis я это знаю. Но в документации я не нашёл такого примера. Хотелось бы ссылку на конкретный примере либо библиотеку

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу свой пример с загрузкой - не понятно, какую авторизацию вы используете.

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя сразу создать файл и назначить ему права. Это делается в два этапа.

> **Важно**. Код без аутентификации. Делайте самостоятельно. Для сервисного аккаунта, доменного пользователя или пользователя системы весь процесс будет одинаковым

### Google Drive API v3

```
import os
import magic
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3')
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

# Создание файл для примера
file_local_path = "/tmp/for_upload.txt"
with open(file_local_path, "w") as f:
    f.write(u"Тут какой-то контент 2")

# Загрузка файла
basename = os.path.basename(file_local_path)
mime = magic.from_file(file_local_path, mime=True)

# Тело запроса загрузки
file_metadata = {"name": basename, "mimeType": mime}

# Конфигурация запроса загрузки
media = MediaFileUpload(file_local_path, mimetype=mime, resumable=True)

# Загрузка
created = (
    drive_service.files()
    .create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields="id,webViewLink")
    .execute()
)

# Тело запроса назначения прав
file_permission = {"role": "reader", "type": "anyone"}

# Назначение прав
drive_service.permissions().create(
    body=file_permission, fileId=created.get("id")
).execute()

# Вывод
print("File ID: {}".format(created.get("id")))
print("File url: {}".format(created.get("webViewLink")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот код

```
 res = DRIVE.files().insert(convert=convert, body=metadata,
        media_body=filename, fields='mimeType,exportLinks,id').execute() # <-- EDIT: added id here
    print('Uploaded file to {url}'.format(url='https://drive.google.com/open?id=' + res.get('id')))
```